# Row highlighting based on due date using php

Tags: php, date, datediff

I'm relatively new to PHP, I've learned procedural PHP and I'm playing around with an app.

I've Looked around the site and found a few samples on date formatting and highlighting using PHP, HTML and CSS.

With the help found here and the PHP manual, I've put together some code to highlight 2 different rows among many others provided by a database that follow this criteria:

- Anything due in 1 day (today, yesterday, last week, etc.) should color the table row red.
- Anything 3 days out (between 1 day and 3 days in the future) should color the table row yellow.
- Anything else should utilize the bootstrap "table-striped" styling.

Here is the code I've put together

```
//Today + 1 day
$oneDay = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+1 day"));
//Today + 3 days
$threeDays = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+3 days"));

//Database entry for comparison
$due = date_create($record['projected_delivery']);

$dueOneDay = date_create($oneDay);
$dueThreeDays = date_create($threeDays);

//Get the difference between the 2 dates
$diffOne = date_diff($due, $dueOneDay);
$diffThree = date_diff($due, $dueThreeDays);

if ($diffThree->format('%d') < 3) {
   $highlight_css = " warning";
}elseif ($diffOne->format('%d') <= 1){
   $highlight_css = " danger";
}else {
   $highlight_css = "";
}
```

I then add the `$highlight_css` to the HTML.

So far *some* of the functionality is working. Proper highlighting is not added for:

- Dates older than 1 day (i.e. yesterday, last week)

How can this functionality be achieved?

Comment: By "1 day or older" do you mean "1 day in the future"?  You days are +1 and +3 not -1 and -3.  Please list some sample data and the expected results vs. the results you are getting.

Comment: I think I may have not specified what I was trying to accomplish properly. I'm trying to highlight upcoming deadlines so for example, if a project is due in 3 days I would like the row to appear yellow then at 1 day red. So far I've been able to accomplish this, my problem is highlighting rows with dates in the past as in yesterday or a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this instead:

```
<?php

$dueDates =["06/05/2017","06/06/2017","06/07/2017","06/08/2017","06/09/2017","06/10/2017","06/11/2017","06/12/2017"];
$table = "<table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th>Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
$today = date_create(date('m/d/Y')); // example: 06/07/2017
foreach ($dueDates as $dueStr) {
    $due = date_create($dueStr);
    $diff = date_diff($today, $due)->format("%r%a");
    $highlight_css = "";
    if ($diff > 1 && $diff <= 3) {
        $highlight_css = " warning";
    } elseif ($diff == 1) {
        $highlight_css = " danger";
    }
    $table .= "<tr class='$highlight_css'><td>$dueStr</td></tr>";
}
$table .= "</tbody></table>";
?>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<?php
echo $table;
```

[image]

Comment: I think I may have not specified what I was trying to accomplish properly. I'm trying to highlight upcoming deadlines so for example, if a project is due in 3 days I would like the row to appear yellow then at 1 day red. So far I've been able to accomplish this, my problem is highlighting rows with dates in the past as in yesterday or a week ago.

Comment: what color should those past dates be? im assuming red?

Comment: I updated my answer. Created a small script that creates an actual HTML table so that you can see what im doing. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ok so in your example image it shows the dates between 6/5/17 and 6/7/17 white, and those are what I've been having problems with in the past. However, I was able to copy your code (which I like far better than what I originally had, thank you!) and update... `} elseif ($diff == 1) {` to `} elseif ($diff <= 1) {` and somehow it does display everything as intended, meaning that anything between 6/5 and 6/8 is highlighted red!

Comment: awesome. Im glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

`$diffThree->format('%d')`

will return a string instead of an integer. In order to compare it correctly with other numbers (3 and 1 in your case) you need to convert it to an int:

`(int) $diffThree->format('%d')`
and

`(int) $diffOne->format('%d')`

Comment: I'm sorry Mike, tried your suggestion adding (int) in front but it returns error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(int)' (int) (T_INT_CAST), expecting '('`

Comment: Does your if statement have all of the parentheses? You might not have the right number

Comment: It was my mistake, I put the `(int)` in the wrong place, however, while following your last comment doesn't give me an error, it brings me back to square one. Anything in the past (yesterday or before) doesn't get any highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

#### The issue

A [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) (the return value of [date_diff()](http://php.net/date_diff)) has the number of days (actually stored in a property [`d`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.d), which could be used instead of getting a string with [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)), which should always be a positive number. And for dates before today's date, the first date diff (i.e. `$diffOne`) will be 2+ days and the second date diff (i.e. `$diffThreeDays`) will be 4+ (see [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/sTzrvVyppWeF8W4M) with debugging output above the table) so days before today's date will never be associated with either '*warning*' or '*danger*' according to the given logic.

#### A Solution

One approach (perhaps simpler) to comparing the dates is to use [DateTime comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2524)

> #### Note:
>
> As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2524)</sup>

So compare the DateTime variables (i.e. `$due` with `$dueOneDay` and `$dueThreeDays`) instead of the date differences.

In the logic below, you will notice that the order of the comparisons has been reversed, so the check for one day difference comes before the check for three days difference, in order to avoid the danger case never happening.

```
if ($due < $dueOneDay){
   $highlight_css = " danger";
}else if ($due <= $dueThreeDays) {
   $highlight_css = " warning";
}else {
   $highlight_css = "";
}
```

With this approach, there is no need for the date_diff variables (i.e. `$diffOne`, `$diffThree`).

See a demonstration of this in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/0HOZ1taeUtkTwYXl).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2524</sub>